# Cuál sería la macro VBA para escribir los valores EDAD Y PESO de un NOMBRE en especifico?

Tags: vba

Supongamos que:

En hoja1 del libro Excel tengo esta tabla:
[image: paciente]
y
En hoja2 del libro Excel tengo esta otra tabla:
[image: grupo etario]

El problema que deseo resolver mediante macro VBA es, que si yo escribo cualquier nombre en la celda A2 de la tabla "Pacientes", y cuyo nombre se halla entre el conjunto de celdas (A2:A4) de la tabla "Grupo etario", entonces la macro rellene automáticamente las celdas B2 y C2 de esta tabla, con los valores que le sean correspondientes al nombre en especifico allí escrito.

Saludos!

Comment: Deberias mirar como [preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) pero ademas debes clarificar tu pregunta, es dificil entender; "celda A2 de la tabla "Pacientes"", ¿Cual es la columna A y cual es la tabla Pacientes?; ¿Cual es la tabla "Grupo etario"?. Puedo instuir cuales son las tablas. Pero además tu pregunta no especifica como se llenarian los datos de las dos tablas a que refieres, ¿De donde saldrian los datos de tu tabla "Grupo etario"?

Comment: Esto se puede hacer con un BUSCARV y listo. ¿Por qué en VBA?

Comment: Amigo Eduardo, ciertamente dejé unas inconsistencias allí, las cuales te voy a aclarar: La tabla "Pacientes" es la que tiene la fila 2 vacía, y esta tabla se haya en la Hoja1 del libro. La tabla "Grupo etario" es la que contiene los datos indicados en las filas 2-3-4, y ella se haya en la Hoja2 del mismo libro. Destaco que la columna "A" es para mi, la primera columna a tu mano izquierda de la tabla "Pacientes". A tu pregunta ¿De donde saldrían los datos de tu tabla "Grupo etario"? te digo que eso no es relevante. Están ahí, y ya. Yo solo deseo que cuando alguien escriba uno de esos tres...

Comment: ....nombres, cualquiera de esos (se entiende, verdad), en la celda A2 de la tabla "Pacientes" (Hoja1), entonces es mi petición que mediante macro VBA (y no con BUSCARV o BUSCARX), la macro pues haga el trabajo de rellenar los campos o celdas B2 y C2 con la información atinente a ese nombre en particular sobre EDAD y PESO que ya están indicadas en la tabla "Grupo etario" (Hoja2). Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, y espero haber sido ahora mas explicito. Saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veamos

En la hoja1, que he denominado Pacientes, pegas éste código (Lo que hace, es mostrar un mensaje de que la celda B6 ha sido cambiada si es que ésta cambia de valor y ejecutar la función ExtraerDatos)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("B6")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "Se ha moificado la celda " & Target.Address & "."
    
        ExtraerDatos

    End If
End Sub
```

Creas un móduglo, y pegas éste otro código (Lo que hace es almacenar en una variable el nombre introducido en la celda B6 de la Hoja1. Luego ejecuta un bucle desde la celda B5 comparando el contenido de las celdas que tengan algún dato y evaluando que coincida el texto con el nombre de la Hoja1.

Si coincide, copia el contenido de las celdas de la derecha, años y peso, y los pega en las celdas correspondentes de la Hoja1

```
Sub ExtraerDatos()

    Sheets("Pacientes").Activate
    Sheets("Pacientes").Select

    Dim nombre As String

    nombre = Range("B6").Text

    Sheets("GrupoEtario").Activate
    Sheets("GrupoEtario").Select
    Range("B5").Select
  
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

         If nombre = ActiveCell.Value Then
             Sheets("Pacientes").Range("C6").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
             Sheets("Pacientes").Range("D6").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Exit Do
         End If
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Amigo el.trasgu, usted es lo máximo, caballero! Tu macro funcionó a la perfección, de acuerdo con mi deseo. Te cuento que solo reemplacé en los códigos las nomenclaturas: B6 por A2, B5 por A2, C6 por B2 y D6 por C2. Y en la hoja "Pacientes" del libro agregué un botón para activar la macro. Chamo, permítame darte un APLAUSO  de pie, y mi sincero AGRADECIMIENTO, así con letras en mayúscula, por Tu valiosa colaboración en el desarrollo de mi proyecto "Aprendiendo macros". Mil gracias, chamo, y dime, por favor, dónde tengo que votar mil veces por ti!!!!

Comment: Amigo, aun estoy pendiente por revisar el proyecto anterior. Luego te aviso de las resultas. Gracias nuevamente, y mis saludos para ti!!!

Comment: Amigo, se me ocurre la idea de que en lugar de activar la macro con el botón, esta macro haga lo mismo pero cuando pulso la tecla ENTER, o haciendo clic con el mouse, luego de escribir el nombre. Te pregunto cuál seria el código adicional que puedo agregar, para hacer eso?

Comment: Hola @victorjulio, el código usa el método "Worksheet_Change", que lo que hace es inicarse automáticamente cada vez que cambies el valor de la celda contenida en la sentencia "Set KeyCells = Range("B6")". O sea, que no tendrías que hacer nada, simplemente cambiar el nombre y dar a la tecla intro.

Comment: Para aceptar la respuesta y cerrar la pregunta, puedes dar al check que te aparece en la parte izquierda de mi respuesta, debajo de los triángulos que apuntan arriba y abajo con un cero en el medio. Esos triángulos son para votar la respuesta, arriba positivo, abajo negativo. El check acepta la respuesta como buena.

Comment: Ahhh, ya vale, tu hiciste una cosa excelente! Entonces mi botón esta demás. Bien eso!!! Bueno, te cuento que yo deseo terminar este proyecto, queriendo hacer que tu macro VBA, con la instrucción ENTER, por ejemplo, me vaya guardando un registro en una tercera hoja del libro, con los mismos datos, y adicionando cada vez una fila en esta tercera hoja, cada vez que yo escriba o repita un nombre en la hoja "Pacientes". Esto es con el fin de insertar posteriormente un grafico interactivo con esos parámetros referenciales. Discúlpame, tanta petición de ayuda, amigo!

Comment: Hola @victorjulio, dado que éste pregunta ya está contestada, te sugiero que formules una nueva pregunta con tu nueva demanda y expliques en ella lo que deseas. Acuérdate de pegar el código relacionado con lo que deseas. Un saludo

Comment: Si no es mucha molestia, dale al check para aceptar la respuesta y así cerrar la pregunta. Un saludo